# 'Add Image' Dialogue Custom 'Block' in Marketing Cloud Content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, custom

I am working on Custom Blocks for Content Builder E-Mails and I wonder if it is possible to choose Image Assets from the Salesforce System like in the 'Image Block'. Sadly I didn't find anything regarding adding images in Custom Blocks.

Comment: I believe you would have to utilize the SFMC API - likely REST (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm)